# Remove html/body border from IE 8 & 7 (5 working)

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I tried to find the answer from one or another question that talked about a related topic but it wasn't exactly this and I didn't got any solution.

I'm trying to remove the 2 pixels width border that shows on Internet Explorer.

Using `border: 0` I got it working on versions 11, 10, 9 and 5 but for some reason 8 and 7 still have it. The code that I'm using is this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html, body {
        border: 0;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        overflow: auto;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is how it looks like (a bit hard to see but it's the gray border around the white background):

[image: IE with border]

Comment: Try `padding:0` . My two cents... I would rather worry about making my site compatible with modern browsers. Do you really believe there is many people using these antics? Also can you try without doctype? Not sure what the support is for IE

Comment: @Mick_ I tried that but it didn't changed the result. I understand that such a tiny thing shouldn't be a big deal but still that's not why I'm gonna just accept it without trying. Removing the doctype also didn't worked.

Comment: I understand. I often get caught doing the same. I don't have ny of these browsers handy to try but i get the feeling its something to do with doctype.

Comment: Just tried downloading it and couldn't even do that. It won't even run on windows 7. That being said its no longer compatible with any up to date operating system.

Comment: @Mick_ You can't download IE? Then how do you [instal other browsers](http://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/624/mcs/media/images/81741000/jpg/_81741183_aa0.jpg)? [Also, I hate it.](http://techstuffed.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/internet-explorer-meme-211-1.jpg.cf_-1.jpg)

Comment: Haha good meme. But honestly i tried on Win 7 VM and it said my version was not compatible.

Comment: *"On January 12, 2016, support for IE8 on all supported Windows operating systems ceased, due to new support policies dictating that only the newest version of IE available for a supported version of Windows is supported."* - [Wikipedia: IE8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8).

Comment: If you get a newer version try to go to the developer tools (press F12) and see if you can emulate an older version from one of the options there.